# Understanding Inheritance in python

Tags: python, inheritance

I am learning OOP in python.

I am struggling why this is not working as I intended?

```
class Patent(object):
    """An object to hold patent information in Specific format"""
    def __init__(self, CC, PN, KC=""):
        self.cc = CC
        self.pn = PN
        self.kc = KC

class USPatent(Patent):
    """"Class for holding information of uspto patents in Specific format"""
    def __init__(self, CC, PN, KC=""):
        Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC="")


pt1 = Patent("US", "20160243185", "A1")

pt2 = USPatent("US", "20160243185", "A1")

pt1.kc
Out[168]: 'A1'

pt2.kc
Out[169]: ''
```

What obvious mistake I am making so that I am not able to get kc in USPatent instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in an empty string:

```
Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC="")
```

That calls the `Patent.__init__()` method setting `KC` to `""`, always.

Pass in whatever value of `KC` you received instead:

```
class USPatent(Patent):
    """"Class for holding information of uspto patents in Specific format"""
    def __init__(self, CC, PN, KC=""):
        Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC=KC)
```

Within `USPatent.__init__()`, `KC` is just another variable, just like `self`, `CC` and `PN`. It is either set to `""` already, or to whatever was passed in when you call `USPatent(...)` with arguments. You simply want to call the `Patent.__init__()` method passing on all the values you have.

You can drop the keyword argument syntax from the call too:

```
Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC)
```

Comment: I still don't understand using KC=KC ?

Comment: @Rahul: would it help if you added `print(CC, PN, KC)` to your function? You'll see what happens to the values.

Comment: @Rahul note that `KC=""` means different things when [defining a function with default keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) as opposed to [calling a function with keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Comment: I know default thing but KC=KC was confusing. Now got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class USPatent(Patent):
    """"Class for holding information of uspto patents in Specific format"""
    def __init__(self, CC, PN, KC=""):
        Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC="")
```

Here you pass `KC`as `""` by coding `KC=""`, instead of `KC=KC`

To pass the inputted `KC`:

```
class USPatent(Patent):
    """"Class for holding information of uspto patents in Specific format"""
    def __init__(self, CC, PN, KC=""):
        Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC="")
```

Should be

```
Patent.__init__(self, CC, PN, KC)
```

The former sets the argument with the name "KC" to the value `""` (the empty string) using the keyword-style argument syntax. What you want is pass the value of the variable `KC` instead.